# zero divisors in polynomial Ring $R[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, roots

How can I find all zero-divisors in the ring $GF(3)[x]_{x^2 + 2x}$?
I know for sure that is a ring and not a field because $x^2+2x$ is reducible.
What I tried is to take: if the  $gcd(m,n)$ not equal $1$ then you get a zero-divisors.
I'm really lost and I don't know how to approce the problem. Is someone that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the nonzero elements in the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_n$ are either units or zero divisors. The elements $m$ with $gcd(m,n)=1$ are units and the remaining nonzero elements are zero divisors.

The same holds for the quotient ring $GF(3)[x]/\langle x(x+2)\rangle$. Those elements which have gcd 1 with $x(x+1)$ are units, the others are zero divisors - bar $0$ which is neither nor.

You can list all elements of $GF(3)[x]/\langle x(x+2)\rangle$ and start from there.

Comment: So basically I need to do $(ax + b)(cx + d)$ is equivalent to Zero mod $x(x+2)$?